# discord.py rewrite | Allow only one instance of a command

Tags: python, discord.py

Whilst using my bot, I discovered that multiple people can use the same command simultaneously. I would only like the command to be ran one at a time, due to it's nature.

Is there a way to ensure there is only one instance of the command running? If there is, please tell me. I need this fixed sort of quickly, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a cooldown for all users with some large timeout, then reset the cooldown at the end of the command:

```
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown

@bot.command()
@cooldown(1, 1000)  # 1000 second cooldown
async def comm(ctx):
    ...
    comm.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

Comment: This is probably a petty question, but I got the error `No module named 'commands` after importing. What did I do wrong with `from commands import cooldown`?

Comment: Whoops, the module I was using already had commands imported. That should be `discord.ext.commands`

Answer (score 0):

Using a global variable is also an option.

```
global set_active
set_active = 0
...
...
@bot.command("turn_on")
async def "Your command name"(ctx):
    global set_active
    #start command
    if set_active == 1:
        await ctx.send("This is already active")
    else/elif:
        ......
    #end command
    set_active = 1

@bot.command("turn_off")
async def "Your command name"(ctx):
    global set_active
    #start command
    ......
    #end command
    set_active = 0
```

I hope this is clear. It is my first time helping somebody.
I have this in my bot too. Let me know if I can help you out more!

Comment: Using the same name for all of your commands isn't great, because then you can't access the `Command` objects later in your code (for stuff like defining groups or command-specific error handlers)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I didn't mean to use the same name for all commands. Just a placeholder for a command. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

Use the @commands.max_concurrecy(number, per=, wait=False) decorator on your command.

Example:

```python
@commands.command()
@commands.max_concurrency(1, per=commands.BucketType.default, wait=False)
async def poll(self, ctx, *question):
    '''
    Code
    '''
```

When using the max_concurrency decorator, if you have wait=False then it will return the MaxConcurrencyReached error when the instances exceeds the number specified. Example of error handling the same command that is above is shown below

Example:

```python
@poll.error
async def poll_handler(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MaxConcurrencyReached):
         (Whatever you want to do here)
```

If wait=True then the command will wait in a queue until it can be ran.

Remember to have this line as well in your bot
`from discord.ext import commands`