# How can I make a command that can only be triggered once?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've made a command that the bot will ask some questions and once you are done answering it the bot will message your answers to a channel..

My problem is that you can trigger the command over and over. Is there a way to make it run only once by a user and can be run again by that user once all of the question is asked?

```
@commands.command(name='test')
@cooldown(1, 60)
async def test(self, ctx):
    if not ctx.guild:
        return
    test = []
    q1 = ['test', 'test']
    channel = self.client.get_channel(733649176373755945)
    dm = await ctx.author.create_dm()

    def check(author):
        def inner_check(message):
            if message.author != author:
                return False
            try:
                str(message.content)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False

        return inner_check

    for question in q1:
        await dm.send(question)
        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author))
        test.append(msg.content)

    answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(test, 1))
    submit = f'\n{answers}'
    await channel.send(submit)
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: added basically it's like that.

Comment: You will need to save data about the users then, this means having a list in working memory (or a seperate file or a database etc.), which you manage and repeatedly update. There is no "easy one way" to do this and discord.py certainly does not have a built-in function for it.

Comment: [Arguably a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853085/discord-py-rewrite-allow-only-one-instance-of-a-command/54854944#54854944).  The only difference is that you would specify a per-user cooldown instead of a global cooldown

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! So I'll just add @cooldown(1, #)?

Comment: Tried adding the cooldown it's working! But it doesn't reset at the end.                 self.client.get_command("test").reset_cooldown(ctx) I also tried adding what you said test.reset_cooldown(ctx) at the end but it doesn't reset it. I get an error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: @Senpai I use [this code to generate checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811719/adding-a-check-issue/55812442#55812442).  I didn't write that answer with Cogs in mind, maybe that changes something.  I'll investigate and write up an answer

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see thank you for the help! I'll wait for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of your code, which does what you want.  I use `self.test.reset_cooldown(ctx)` to reset the cooldown:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_util import message_check

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 100, commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.dm_only()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        answers = []
        questions = ["test1", "test2"]
        for question in questions:
            dm = await ctx.author.send(question)
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=dm.channel, author=ctx.author))
            answers.append(msg.content)
        answer_str = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(answers, 1))
        await ctx.send(f"\n{answer_str}")
        self.test.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

You can find my [`message_check` code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811719/adding-a-check-issue/55812442#55812442)

Comment: Forgot the self... Haha. Cooldown is working now thank you! But I'm having an error with the check     msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=dm.channel, author=ctx.author))
AttributeError: 'DMChannel' object has no attribute 'channel'

Comment: You have some code `dm = await ctx.author.create_dm()`, whereas in my code `dm` is the message we send to the user.  (You don't need to manually get the DM channel, as you can `send` straight to the user.)